# CodeBlock undefined reference to Windows API function even though search directory is configured

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, codeblocks

I'm trying to compile a little program using minGw compiler with Code::Blocks. My program looks like follows:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    int main()
    {
        HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "A Valid Window Title");
        printf("Window Handle=%X\n", hwnd);
        DWORD pid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        printf("PID=%d\n", pid);
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
        printf("Process HANLDE=%X\n", hProcess);
        GetProcessId(hProcess);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 0;
    }
```

However, Code::Blocks yields an `undefined reference to GetProcessId`  error when I try to compile. If I delete the call to `GetProcessId`, the program compiles and runs normally. I thought this error message is caused by incorrect search path. So I went to my settings and add

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
```

To my search directory. But this time, Code::Blocks yields even more error. My second thought was maybe this is caused by some linking error. So I went to my  setting and explicitly add `Kernel32.lib` and `User32.lib` to my project. The same error still occurs. What confuses my more is when I type `GetProcessId`, the suggestion actually comes up and indicates that there is a function named `GetProcessId` [image]

What's the cause of such problem and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Search path has nothing to do with it. You have to link the right libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetProcessId` requires at least Windows XP SP1. It's safe to assume nobody uses older operating systems, so you can add `#define WINVER 0x0501` to indicate minimum operating system. Put this at the beginning of the file or in some .h file which is used by all *.cpp files

```
#define WINVER 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
...
}
```

Edited ---- see comments

Comment: I meant to write `0x0501` for Windows XP, but I had put `0x0510`. I fixed it now.